# Relationship between random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> If $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ are identical and independently distributed random variables with density function $f$, then what is the probability that
>   a) $P(X_3 <\max(X_1,X_2)<X_4)$
>   b) $P(\max(X_1,X_2)<X_3<X_4)$.

How to proceed in this because there is no pdf no information. What is the main concept for this question?

Comment: Have you heard about rank statistics?

Comment: No but i have heard about order statistics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rank statistic of a random vector $X=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is the vector $R=(R_1,\dots R_n)$ where $R_i$ is the rank of $X_i$ in the vector. It is $1$ if it's the smallest value, $2$ if it's the second smallest and so on.

Note that if you know the rank statistic *and* the order statistic, you know $X$.

What is interesting is that if the $X_i$ are i.i.d, the distribution of $R$ is the uniform distribution over the set of permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. This is an intuitive result. As the values are i.i.d., there is no reason to get one ordering more than another (we assume here that there are no ties).

Thus, to answer the questions, all you have to do is determine the number of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ that satisfy the condition, and divide it by $4!=24$ (the total number of permutations). For example for (b) there are $X_1<X_2<X_3<X_4$ or $X_2<X_1<X_3<X_4$, and others...

Comment: Thnx augustin..